# Post Array using AJAX to MVC C#

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I am trying to post an array to my MVC Action but I continue to receive a null value.

```
    //Send List of services to controller
$('#submitButton').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Appointments/GetListOfServices',
        data: JSON.stringify({ CheckedItems: checkedItems }),
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.Result);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            $('#result').html(response);
            console.log("failed");
        }
    }); 
});
```

When I call the `GetListOfServices` function I am receiving a null value

```
        public JsonResult GetListOfServices(int[] CheckedItems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(CheckedItems);
        return Json(new { message= "OK" });
    }
```

When I examine the console and the Network tabs in my browser, it is showing the following:

[image: Network Image]

Comment: You're sending an object not an array.

Comment: You're sending a JSON string containing objects. If you want to pass raw array, use `traditional: true` option & don't use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: what is this... this code is not a proper to deliver the content, try use httppost instead of get

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto If I follow your suggestion, I still have a null value but instead my query string parameters are "undefined"

Comment: Use `HttpPost` in `JsonResult` action and `type: 'POST'` in your AJAX. The JS array is never intended to use with `GET` method which sends data through query string.

Comment: @ryan1555 I am passing value in an array to use in a function. I have not put the full code for the function though. I have done similar when passing a single variable of type int or string and it works perfectly. I am having trouble with the array though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you should consider is if the array content is large, then array contents may exceed the query string limit, hence you may try using `POST` method instead. If you want to pass array as controller action parameter, you need to set `traditional: true` option in AJAX call:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET' // or 'POST'
        traditional: true,
        url: '/Appointments/GetListOfServices',
        data: { CheckedItems: checkedItems },
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.message);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            $('#result').html(response);
            console.log("failed");
        }
    }); 
});
```

As an alternative, you can use `$.param()` with `traditional` property set to `true`:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET', // or 'POST'
        url: '/Appointments/GetListOfServices',
        data: $.param({ CheckedItems: checkedItems }, true),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.message);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            $('#result').html(response);
            console.log("failed");
        }
    }); 
});
```

Finally, don't forget to mark `JsonResult` action as `POST` method by adding `[HttpPost]` attribute **only if you're using POST**:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetListOfServices(int[] CheckedItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(CheckedItems);
    return Json(new { message= "OK" });
}
```

If you're using GET, make sure `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` is set:

```
public JsonResult GetListOfServices(int[] CheckedItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(CheckedItems);
    return Json(new { message= "OK" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Note:** You can try shorter syntax with `jQuery.getJson()`, but still requires `traditional: true` option:

```
$.getJSON('/Appointments/GetListOfServices', $.param({ CheckedItems: checkedItems }, true), function (data) {
    alert(data.message);
});
```

With this setup, the array should be properly received as action method parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to remove `Json.stringify` (unless you want to create `Custom Model Binder` to convert json string to int[]) then it will works.

You also need to add `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` in your controller action

```
return Json(new { message = "OK", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
```

to allow Get response in JSON